# Drawing points with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of points in the form of

```
points=[(x1,y1),...(xn,yn)...]
```

I am looking for a pythonic way to transform the list into

```
 x=[x1,...xn] y=[y1,...yn]
```

One way to do it would be

```
x = map (lambda x: x[1],points)
```

However,  maybe there is a more pythonic way to directly draw from "points" mentioned above?

Comment: Do you mind using anything like numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
x = []
y = []
for point in points:
   x.append(point[0])
   y.append(point[1])
```

or:

```
x,y = [i[0] for i in points],  [i[1] for i in points]
```

but the best way is to use `zip`:

```
x,y = zip(*points)
```

`zip` is better than `map` and it is faster, you should define a function in map with `lambda`. so I think the best way to do this is with `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mehrdad-pedramfar answer:

If using numpy is not a problem you can convert your list of tuples to a numpy array and then just use indexing.

```
import numpy as np

short_example = np.array([(1,2),(2,4),(4,6)])
short_example[:,0]
```

gives a numpy array of all x values:

```
array([1, 2, 4])

short_example[:,1]
```

gives a numpy array of all y values:

```
array([2, 4, 6])
```